# Is the windows 10 product key in BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, bios, product-key

My new laptop's preinstalled Windows 10 was activated as soon as it was connected to the internet. But no product keys were shown to me. There is no product key label on the laptop. Somewhere I read for newer laptops the product key is embedded in Bios. How can I be sure that if I reinstall the Windows using  Media Creation Tool ISO file, it will not ask for the unavailable product key and will detect it in Bios (if any keys is embedded there)?

Comment: https://itstillworks.com/what-is-a-slic-bios-entry-10065.html

Answer (score 6):

Get into command prompt by searching for it or doing the Windows key and R button and typing `cmd` (it should pop up). 
Then type this command in exactly as is:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

And your product key should pop up right after. voila

Comment: That’s `OA3x` with a capital letter O (and not a zero) – for those who cannot copy and paste.

Comment: ERROR: Description = Not Found

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM | tail -1
```

Use this to view your product key from a live Ubuntu distro on pendrive

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has made it simple to activate Windows 10.

On new machines the product key is stored in BIOs and is used automatically by the Windows when connected to the Internet.

In Windows 10 hardware activation is used. Your Windows 10 will be automatically activated until you don't make changes to the hardware.

If you want to install same version as fresh no problem click I don't have a product key link during installation and it will be activated automatically.

You can also switch between 32-bit and 64-bit without need of a key in the same edition.

If you want to see OEM details visit Microsoft live and check devices tab. You will get everything there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Windows 10 key is stored in the BIOS, in the event you need a restore, as long as you use the same version so either Pro or Home, it will activate automatically.

You can prove this to your self, by downloading any product key finder on google and the last 5 digits will be displayed for you. Also the code is normally placed on a sticker under the laptop or under the battery.

Thanks!

Comment: "Also the code is normally placed on a sticker under the laptop or under the battery." - This is 100% false.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, it is 100% - 3 (my machines that had Windows pre-installed). Isn't that actually pretty common?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - Windows 10 COA stickers DO NOT have the license key printed on them.  The author made no mention of the device originally having Windows 7 installed on it. In fact, the device had Windows 10 preinstalled, which means the COA sticker DOES NOT have the license key printed on it.  **So this answer is factually incorrect.**  Your machines must have not had Windows 10 preinstalled and thus are not applicable to my comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, there was a change between W7 and W10? Yes, I was probably refering to Win7 or perhaps 8.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - It changed with Windows 8.  So it changed 10+ years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Download & install Magical Jelly Bean Key Finder from here: https://www.magicaljellybean.com/downloads/KeyFinderInstaller.exe

This app reads the product keys of Windows & many other apps (Photoshop, MS Office, IDM, etc.) from the registry & shows it to you. You can easily find out the product key of your installed windows (any version).

In my laptop (Dell Inspiron 1440) the product key of the pre-installed Win7 Pro was written on a sticker at the bottom of my laptop. You can also check at the bottom of your laptop.

Comment: Magical Jelly Bean does not have the capability to read the license key from the ACPI table which is where the Windows 10 license key is stored.